# How to return ids from 'list' in 'list of objects', and use inside a resource looping through each object

Tags: terraform

I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible. Here is the flow of operations:

### Input

Input is being provided like so:

```
rule_lists = [
  {
    name  = "list1"
    rules = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3"]
  },
  {
    name  = "list2"
    rules = ["rule8", "rule9", "otherrule"]
  }
]
```

### Variables

Into a variable of this type:

```
variable "rule_lists" {
  type = list(object({
    name     = string
    rules    = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

### What needs to happen

I need to query each 'rule' in each list of rules in each object for its ID (The resource to create this "rule-list" object will only take IDs and not human readable names). The resource in this provider that returns an ID for each rule looks like this:

```
data "rule" "rule" {
  name = "rule"
}
```

### My Attempt

My lovely attempt at making this work is appending the IDs of all rules in each object and attempting to create the rule-lists with every rule of every object.

```
locals {
  filter_rules = flatten([
    for list in var.rule_list_data : [
      for rule in list.rules : 
        rule
    ]
  ])

  # filter rule IDs
  rule_id_list = [
    for v in data.alkira_policy_rule.rule : v.id
    if var.rule_list == true
  ]

}

data "rule" "rule" {

  # filter existing rule names to ids
  for_each = {
    for k, v in toset(local.filter_rules) : k => v
  }

  name = each.value

}

resource "rule_list" "rule_list" {

  for_each = {
    for o in var.rule_list_data : o.name => o
  }

  name        = each.value.name

  dynamic "rules" {
    for_each = local.rule_id_list

    content {
      priority = format("%d", rules.key + 1)
      rule_id  = rules.value
    }

  }

}
```

The final resource 'rule_list' that the IDs are provided takes the rule IDs in a nested schema with a priority value also. As seen above, I'm just incrementing the priority value for each rule +1 with each new rule added to the list. If I were creating a single rule list with 2 rules without any loops etc., it would look like this:

```
resource "rule_list" "list" {
  name = "rule-list-name"
  rule = {
    priority = 1
    rule_id  = data.rule.rule1.id
  }
  rule = {
    priority = 2
    rule_id = data.rule.rule2.id
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer this with getting a little more creative in lookups:

```
locals {

   filter_rule_lists = flatten([
    for list in var.rule_list_data : {
        name         = list.name
        description  = list.description
        rules        = [for rule in list.rules : lookup(data.alkira_policy_rule.rule, rule, null)]
      }
  ])
```